# What should you do after Havdalah?

Tags: grapes-wine, havdalah

After the you finish saying Havdalah what should you do? some examples.

1. Dipping your pinkies into the wine and rubbing it on yourself. Where are supposed to do it? etc.
2. Pouring the wine over the candle
3. And one time I saw someone smelling the Havdalah candle after Havdalah?

If you have sources that would be the best.

Comment: You should drink a cheekful of wine.

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/dipping-fingers-in-havdalah-wine

Comment: Another partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17405/why-extinguish-the-havdala-candle-in-wine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rubbing the Havdalah wine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/rubbing-the-havdalah-wine)

Comment: @Danf there are a few reasons why it is not (in my opinion) 1. I am asking a more general question 2. It does not say where you should rub it.

Comment: @user6781 - Ah yes, I didn't consider #3, which isn't addressed in any of the other questions.

Comment: @user6781 - I saw #3 done too by one of my Yekke friends. He was the only one I saw do it, many years ago. If my memory is correct, when I asked him why he does that, he said, "because burning alcohol smells good!"

Comment: @user6781 - It was a refernce to YOUR memory ... the person I asked was male :-)

Comment: @DanF Lets redo this. Your post is funny, a similar thing happened to me when I asked a girl why she was smelling the candle and she said something about memory

Comment: wash and eat melava malka meal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Most customs I've seen put wine on their eye lids or over the eyes in keeping with the verse "Mitvat Hashem Barah Me'irat enayim" - "G-d's commandments enlighten the eyes". They also rub it in their pockets as a sign of parnassa.

2 - Done as a sign of a good omen for parnassah that the wine should be poured like water.

Sources for 1 & 2 are in the links mentioned in above comments.

3 - For what it's worth, see [2nd comment in this blog](http://askshifra.blogspot.com/2005/11/thoughts-on-havdalah.html) that says it's an omen for courage. I don't quite get the idea. As I stated in my comments, I've seen only 1 person do this. Let's just say that he WAS a good friend. Now, you know why...