# Why do people put wine in their pockets at havdalah?

Tags: minhag, grapes-wine, havdalah

This is a minhag that many people observe at havdalah but I don't know the source or why people do it.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12061. Also see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12055.

Comment: no it's not a duplicate because I know a lot of people who put wine in their pockets at havdalah for parnassah and other segulos

Comment: Your comment appears to have answered your own question: "for parnassah and other segulos".

Comment: Is putting wine in one's pockets common? Could there be other reasons to do so other than for (or in addition to) parnassah and segulot? For example, perhaps to symbolically take the sweetness of Shabbat with them until next Shabbat?

Comment: I have not read the article but here is a possible answer from Yeshiva World @AviKupchik: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/havdalah-putting-wine-on-your-eyes-and-in-your-pocket

Comment: @AviKupchik That post includes clothing so this is subsumed under that.