# Where does the minhag of holding a pinky up to the Torah come from?

Tags: minhag, passover

Where does the *minhag* to hold a pinky up to the Torah during *hagbah* come from? And in the same vein (or perhaps not) where does the *minhag* to dip your pinky into your cup on Pesach to remove wine come from?

Comment: Duplicate of [Reason behind pinky during hagba](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/reason-behind-pinky-during-hagba) and [dipping fingers in Havdalah wine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/dipping-fingers-in-havdalah-wine)

Comment: also of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15479/759

Comment: Neither of those other questions explain WHY it's the pinky finger.

Comment: @devirkahan Do you mean none of the answers there explain why it's the pinky finger, or that none of those question ASK about the pinky finger?

Comment: @DoubleAA They don't explain why it's the pinky finger, specifically. I read through the whole pages, and know that it's a Sefardic custom, but why is it the pinky finger?

Comment: @devirkahan You didn't answer my question. Is it that the _answers_ don't discuss the pinky, or the _questions_ don't discuss the pinky? If you agree the questions are the same then it is a duplicate question.

Comment: Ah, I follow. You're saying I should follow-up with comments in the other question as opposed to making a new question to clarify. No problem. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Whoops, I need to read more carefully. I chose the wrong question for my second "dupe".

Comment: You can also see the relevant part of the [FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty)